# SharePoint 2010 People Search "My Colleague" or "My Colleague's Colleague"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, people-search

People search results show either "My Colleague" or "My Colleague's Colleague" under some users profile picture.

- What is this setting?
- Why does it appear?
- How can it be removed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**What is this setting?**

It's `My Colleagues policy` in `User Profile Sync Service` that working when you have configured `My Site`. check also [Add new colleagues and manage your colleague list](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-new-colleagues-and-manage-your-colleague-list-325f858b-c417-4f47-93d3-658535b322b4).

**Why does it appear?**

by default, the colleague's scan policy is enabled.

**How can it be removed?**

You can disable `My Colleagues policy` as the following:

- Open Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Service Applications
- Click on User Profile Sync Service. from the above ribbon click `Manage`.
- Below `People`, Click on `Manage Policies`.
- Search for `My Colleagues`, Click on it to edit its setting.
- Below the `Policy Setting`, Select **Disabled**.

[image]

Comment: In SharePoint 2010, I have My Colleagues - Colleagues on My Site, Auto-population of colleagues from organizations and Colleague Recommendation.  The Policy Setting for "Colleagues on My Site" is grayed out and I can't change it to Disabled.

Comment: Make sure the current user is farm account and open central admin as administrator!

Comment: Still unable to change setting after verifying current user is a farm account and opening CA as administrator.